surprisingly vs surprising

Over its long history, the Supreme Court has ruled on  many contentious legal issues: slavery and racial segregation, free speech and religious freedom, abortion and marriage equality. Perhaps it is not surprisingly, then, that our nation’s highest court has also weighed in on the biggest controversy ever debated in the produce aisle: whether the tomato is a fruit or a vegetable.

From
https://blogs.kentlaw.iit.edu/iscotus/supreme-court-great-tomato-debate/
It seems to me that the writer bothers to use surprisingly instead of surprising.
So my question is
Is there any nuances between surprisingly and surprising in this sentence ?

It looks very much like the write made an error.

I’m voting to close this question because the question is fine, but it is just a mistake, so there is not proper answer


*Perhaps it is not surprisingly, then, that our nation’s highest court has also weighed in on ...

I rephase to show the structure
SUBJECT + PREDICATOR + SUBJECT COMPLEMENT
where the subject complement should be an adjective here, surprising:
[that our nation’s highest court has also weighed in on ...] is [not surprising]
Hence

it is not [surprising], then, that our nation’s highest court has also weighed in on ...

